# How to create an extra box in this figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have now spent hours by solving my problem - without luck. I would like to create the following figure:

[image]

My problem is, that I do not know, how to create an extra box in the middle. My preamble look like this (Thanks to @Ignasi for leading me in the right direction):

```
\documentclass[margin=14pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
mytext/.style={
  draw,
  text width=#1,
  align=center,
  minimum height=1.5cm
  },
ar/.style={
  ->,
  >=latex
  }  
]
\node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm] (left)
  {1 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,right=1.5cm of left] 
  (middle2)
  {2 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,anchor=north west] at (left.north-|middle2.west) 
  (middle1)
  {3 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,anchor=south west] at (left.south-|middle2.west) 
  (middle3)
  {4 text text text};
\node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm,right=1.5cm of middle2] (right)
  {8 text text text};


\node[mytext=3cm, dashed, above=1cm of left] (d-left) {1 text text};
\node[mytext=4cm, dashed, above=1cm of middle1] (d-middle) {2 text text};
\node[mytext=3cm, dashed, above=1cm of right] (d-right) {3 text text};

\foreach \i/\j in {1/d-left, 2/d-middle, 3/d-right}
    \draw ([yshift=1cm]\j.north west)--node [above] {\i\ text} ([yshift=1cm]\j.north east);

\foreach \i in {middle1, middle2, middle3}{
    \draw[ar] (left.east)--(\i.west);
    \draw[ar] (\i)--(right.west|-\i);
    }

\node[fit={(left) (right) ([yshift=2cm]d-left.north west)}, draw, inner sep=8,,] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I would appreciate any kind of help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just added few `yshift` with appropriate values (1.1cm) and an extra node `middle21`.

```
\documentclass[margin=14pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[lf]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
mytext/.style={
  draw,
  text width=#1,
  align=center,
  minimum height=1.5cm
  },
ar/.style={
  ->,
  >=latex
  }
]
\node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm] (left)
  {1 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,right=1.5cm of left,yshift=1.1cm]
  (middle2)
  {2 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,right=1.5cm of left,yshift=-1.1cm]
  (middle21)
  {2 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,anchor=north west] at (left.north-|middle2.west)
  (middle1)
  {3 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,anchor=south west] at (left.south-|middle2.west)
  (middle3)
  {4 text text text};
\node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm,right=1.5cm of middle2,yshift=-1.1cm] (right)
  {8 text text text};


\node[mytext=3cm, dashed, above=1cm of left] (d-left) {1 text text};
\node[mytext=4cm, dashed, above=1cm of middle1] (d-middle) {2 text text};
\node[mytext=3cm, dashed, above=1cm of right] (d-right) {3 text text};

\foreach \i/\j in {1/d-left, 2/d-middle, 3/d-right}
    \draw ([yshift=1cm]\j.north west)--node [above] {\i\ text} ([yshift=1cm]\j.north east);

\foreach \i in {middle1, middle2,middle21, middle3}{
    \draw[ar] (left.east)--(\i.west);
    \draw[ar] (\i)--(right.west|-\i);
    }

\node[fit={(left) (right) ([yshift=2cm]d-left.north west)}, draw, inner sep=8,,] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If I would like to change switch different in "1 text", "2text" and "3 text" how do I do that

Comment: @A.F. I think I didn't follow your comment. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I think I maybe found a solution. \foreach \i/\j in {{ 1text}/d-left, { 2text}/d-middle, { 3text}/d-right}
    \draw ([yshift=1cm]\j.north west)--node [above] {\i\ } ([yshift=1cm]\j.north east);

Comment: I do not know, why the middle text box is lower than the two others

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option using the `calc` library to place the intermediate boxes in the middle; I tried to modify the less possible your original code:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[margin=14pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, fit,calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
mytext/.style={
  draw,
  text width=#1,
  align=center,
  minimum height=1.5cm
  },
ar/.style={
  ->,
  >=latex
  }  
]
\node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm] (left)
  {1 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,anchor=north west]
  at ([xshift=1.5cm]$ (left.north east)!0.27!(left.south east) $ ) 
  (middle2)
  {2 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,anchor=south west]
  at ([xshift=1.5cm]$ (left.north east)!0.73!(left.south east) $ ) 
  (middle3)
  {3 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,anchor=north west] at (left.north-|middle2.west) 
  (middle1)
  {1 text text text};
\node[mytext=4cm,anchor=south west] at (left.south-|middle2.west) 
  (middle4)
  {4 text text text};
\node[mytext=3cm,minimum height=8cm,right=1.5cm of middle1.north east,anchor=north west] (right)
  {8 text text text};


\node[mytext=3cm, dashed, above=1cm of left] (d-left) {1 text text};
\node[mytext=4cm, dashed, above=1cm of middle1] (d-middle) {2 text text};
\node[mytext=3cm, dashed, above=1cm of right] (d-right) {3 text text};

\foreach \i/\j in {1/d-left, 2/d-middle, 3/d-right}
    \draw ([yshift=1cm]\j.north west)--node [above] {\i\ text} ([yshift=1cm]\j.north east);

\foreach \i in {middle1, middle2, middle3, middle4}{
    \draw[ar] (left.east)--(\i.west);
    \draw[ar] (\i)--(right.west|-\i);
    }

\node[fit={(left) (right) ([yshift=2cm]d-left.north west)}, draw, inner sep=8,,] {};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```